# Jquery Background Fader

Tags: jquery, background, duration, fading

I have a script that works, however the background images are "popping" in and not fading in and out smoothly. They change instantly. I am only testing 2 backgrounds right now, not 4.

This is my new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7K3a/).

It is only toggling between the 1st background image and the 4th.

EDIT: New JQuery is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
      $("body").toggleClass('background2', 1000);
      $("body").toggleClass('background3', 1000);
      $("body").toggleClass('background4', 1000);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: why not use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`?

Comment: I honestly cant write jquery. Learning. So use: $body.fadeIn('background2', 1000); for example? <<< Well, that didnt work. Might you illustrate your point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319552/can-i-fade-in-a-background-image-css-background-image-with-jquery

Comment: There is no code here that attempts to fade smoothly.

Comment: Popnoodles, that is why I am asking for help. :) 
Fabricator, checking that stack now. Will post answer if it helps.

Comment: Do you want fadeIn images in sequence? then this links is usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018819/how-to-fade-in-images-in-sequence

Comment: Yes, @sany2k8. However how do I attach this sequence to the body, through an array?

Comment: Try this way, 

foreach($imagearray as $img) {
    echo "<img src='images/$img' />";
}                                                                   this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460911/retrieving-an-array-of-images-on-html-page-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use jQuery UI's [`toggleClass()` function](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/).

```
$(element).toggleClass('otherClass', duration);
```

In your case, you'd set the initial class of the body to `background1` and toggle between the other classes. I've set that up for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/2upwr/8/), but the reason why you're not seeing anything is because all of your classes point to **the same image**.

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/2upwr/4/), where I've commented out your images and used simple colors.

Comment: Ah, I see how this works. Thank you for the assistance. When I take out the colors and try it with the images it still pops in instantly with no transition. background1 and background2 are different, though background2's only difference is a slight green tint. I wanted this to be a subtle background affect. Any way I can use RGBa and just overlay a 0.2 opacity color over 1 original background image 4 times?

Comment: @FlannelBeard I updated the first link to toggle through all four classes and, unless my eyes are deceiving me (which is entirely possible), I see no change between them at all. They shouldn't be jumping in: the only reason I can think that it would do it initially is because it has to load the image from the external source before it sets it as the background, in which case I would recommend downloading the image and using it locally.

Comment: Cant be, its a small png repeated. Here is my [dev theme](http://www.elevancement.com/novus-theme/). I made the saturation on those background images high so you can see the difference. Still pops in. Im learning a lot of jquery tonight through this so thank you. I wonder why its not fading... it does it with colors. Hmm. The other issue is that it only toggles between the 4th class now. Maybe we need an array?

Comment: @FlannelBeard It may not be able to fade through images because it is not immediately obvious how those images are connected. It appears to you that the images are the same with slight variation, but jQuery does not know anything outside of the fact that they are different images.

Comment: Also, to combat what all the others are saying, you can't really use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`, because you're changing a background image. Unless you want to overlay a `div` on the entire page, those won't help you much.

Comment: Understood, this is a huge learning experience / curve for me. I am still trying some things out... I might be approaching this all wrong.

Comment: CSS animations might be what you're looking for, but I haven't really looked into that topic much, so I'm not the one to ask about those.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery fadein and fadeout. Take a look at this simple example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_fadeout_fadein

Comment: I know, but the addClass / removeClass cannot include a fadeIn fadeOut. It has duration but it is not affecting the fade.

Comment: You cannot use add/remove class. You can only fade in/out an element. Here is an example of using fading in different background images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825194/fade-in-background-jquery